# Handling RateLimitError in OpenAI API while using Google Colab

Tags: openai-api

I'm trying to generate academic papers using OpenAI's API in Google Colab. However, I'm encountering a `RateLimitError` that says "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details." Here's the code I'm using:

```py
!pip install openai
# Import the necessary libraries and set up the API key
import openai

openai.api_key = "your_openai_api_key"

# Define the prompts
prompts = [
"List"# List of prompts for generating academic papers
]

# Function to generate an academic paper
def generate_academic_paper(prompt):
 model_engine = "text-davinci-003"
 max_tokens = 2048

 completion = openai.chat.completions.create(
  model=model_engine,
  messages=[{"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
           {"role": "user", "content": prompt}],
  max_tokens=max_tokens,
  temperature=0.8,
  top_p=1,
  frequency_penalty=0,
  presence_penalty=0 )
return completion

import time
# Function to generate academic papers for given prompts
def generate_papers(prompts):
  for prompt in prompts:
      response = generate_academic_paper(prompt)
      print(response)
      print("loop")
      time.sleep(2)

# Generate academic papers for the given prompts
generate_papers(prompts)
```

I've already checked my OpenAI account and I'm sure that I haven't exceeded the quotaas you can see at below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw9Ou.jpg)

I've also tried adding a delay between requests using `time.sleep(2)`, but I'm still encountering the error. I've also attached a screenshot of my OpenAI account showing that I haven't exceeded the quota. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?